# How to fix timeout for packages on `npm install`?

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I run `npm install` it seems to work fine until part way installing packages. It seems to have no problem with the first half, but then after a while it will fail to be able to reach other packages. I just get the repeating errors, eg:

```
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-hot-loader
npm info attempt registry request try #3 at 6:43:34 AM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-tap-event-plugin
npm info attempt registry request try #3 at 6:43:34 AM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-test-renderer
```

etc.

It will continue to do this for an hour and and then the install will fail.

The install breaks at a different package each time so I don't think it's a problem with a particular file.

I can access these files fine with my browser and `curl`.

My work has a firewall but this domain is whitelisted.

Would anyone know what I could do to get this to work or what could be causing it?

Answer (score 30):

If it's about the timing problem you should find a speed solutions for npm install.

So you can try these faster command than npm install  :

`pnpm install` %70 faster
or
`npm install --no-audit` 15% faster
or
`npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit` 15% faster

check this article for details : [speeding up npm install](http://www.tiernok.com/posts/2019/faster-npm-installs-during-ci/)

Comment: For me, my issue was that on a machine that doesn't have access to the internet and that installs from a private NPM registry, `npm install` would hang at the very end of the install (usually for about 4 minutes). Installing with `--no-audit` fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: pnpm caches the node_modules in your local file system so it makes sense that it's faster than npm locally, but is pnpm always faster in a fresh environment like Docker?

Answer (score 20):

You can override the max and min timeout in `~/.npmrc`.

```
// npm config ls -l
// add these 2 lines in ~/.npmrc
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 6000000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 1000000
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 14):

If your internet connection is the problem, try increasing the timeout:

```
npm config set timeout 6000000
```

The value is a 32-bit int.

Comment: This was exactly my problem on a WLAN, thank you! I assume it's milliseconds, so that `6000000 / 1000 / 60` = timeout of 100 minutes?

Comment: @kungfooman  it's 10 minutes.  (600000 miliseconds/1000 miliseconds per second) -> 600 seconds / 60 seconds per minute --> 10 minutes

Comment: I've started getting the error `The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string` after running this command.

Comment: I am getting the same error as well The timeout type must be number.
Have found the fix yet?

Comment: no it's 6 MILLION milliseconds, so actually 100 minutes...

Answer (score 7):

If it's still relevant or maybe for other people of interest: For me it helped, deleting the package.lock file and running `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: This helped me. it turned out that npm has to small timeout values for download connections and connections where killed while downloading packages. To solve this clear cache like in this post and install dependencies one by one.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend timeout with those two commands:

```
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 6000000
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 1000000
```

[image]

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#fetch-retry-maxtimeout

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to migrate from 14 to 15 anuglar version

this is the error i am getting The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string '100000'

dont why its getting type error even though it number in .npmrc file

Answer (score 1):

It might not be your case, but I had issues with a package being hosted at github with the repo url being only with git protocol (port 9418 not usually open on firewall).

Once added that to the firewall I could npm install without issues.

You can view the repository url with:

```
$ npm view zone.js repository.url
git://github.com/angular/angular.git
```

Comment: how to add this to firewall pls?

Comment: @404 you just need to open the port for outgoing traffic, your firewall admin will know the specifics in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I saw an answer earlier that can resolve your problem by overriding the max and min timeout in ~/.npmrc file, but some didn't understand how to do it.
First go to the **nodejs** folder - for me it's located at **(** *Y:\Program Files\nodejs* **)**

- Open the **node_modules** folder.
- Then **npm** folder.
- Select (**.npmrc**) file + right click and open it with any text editor you want.
- Finally add these 2 lines and click *Ctrl+S*

```
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 6000000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 1000000
```

[.npmrc file after modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXS2j.png)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
npm cache clean --force

npm install --force
```

It works fine.

Comment: --force on npm install seems unrelated, here's a quote from npm help install: 'npm  will  refuse  to install any package with an identical name to the
       current package. This can be overridden with the --force flag,  but  in
       most  cases can simply be addressed by changing the local package name.'

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, try running vscode as administrator, it worked for me, I tried `npm config delete https-proxy` , `npm config delete proxy`   and  , tried deleting node_modules, and package.lock.json and ran `npm cache clean --force`   but at last ran vscode as adminitrator before deleting node_modules and package.lock.json, it worked

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the provided suggestions like `npm cache clean --force` or removing `package-lock.json`.

Funnily enough, what helped me in the end is `sudo reboot` and clearing cache with `npm cache clean --force` afterwards

Answer (score -2):

I solved the *timeout* issue by executing these commands:

```
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```