# npm not working, shows Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, npm

Every time I try to install a package I get the error message shown below.

I have tried everything, please help me.

> ```
> npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/base-config-process (over 30000ms)
> ```

Comment: Check out the image ,i tried everything, it does not work, i even reinstalled node again, but nothing works, please help me as i am working on a project with a deadline, I need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434006/how-to-fix-timeout-for-packages-on-npm-install Is this SO question helpful?

Comment: tried it does not work.

Comment: This is too little information for someone else to go on. The resource loads fine for me. It's probable there is something wrong with your network. You could also check your npm config, people tend to have config settings interfering. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025719/node-js-npm-install-express-failed-to-fetch-from-registry . You could also try using your phone as a hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **timeout flag**. I had the same error when I tried to install cordova because a bad internet connection. Then I did this:

`npm i -g --timeout=120000 cordova`

and it worked for me, so I hope it works for you as well