# ERROR Unclean working tree. Commit or stash changes first

Tags: runtime-error, pnpm

I got npm timeout error so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434006/how-to-fix-timeout-for-packages-on-npm-install).
When I run `pnpm publish --otp=111111`, I got this error :

> ERROR  Unclean working tree. Commit or stash changes first.

What means this error ? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

pnpm from v5 will not allow you to make a publish if you have changes in the repository that are not committed.

If you still want to publish, you may use the `--no-git-checks` option. For example, `pnpm publish --no-git-checks`. Or you can create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project and set it permanently: `git-checks=false`.

These are all the git checks that are performed by pnpm, when `git-checks` is `true`:

- current branch is your publish branch (master by default)
- repository is clean
- repositroy is up-to-date.